# Reverse INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql

I’m creating a site for a local football team. To view the matches I’m using 2 tables vid. teams (all the information of a team) and matches.
To have an overview of all the matches I use this query:

```
SELECT matches.matchid, CONCAT( ELT( DAYOFWEEK( matches.matchdate ) ,'zon', 'maa', 'din', 'woe', 'don', 'vrij', 'zat' ) , ' ', 
DAYOFMONTH( matches.matchdate ) , ' ', 
ELT( MONTH( matches.matchdate ) , 'jan', 'feb', 'maa', 'apr', 'mei','jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec' ) ,' ',
year( matches.matchdate )
) AS datum_NL, TIME_FORMAT( matches.matchtime, '%H:%i' ) AS UUR  
matches.matchtype, matches.division, matches.season, teams.teamname AS thuisploeg, teamhomescore.teamname AS bezoekers, matches.homescore, matches.awayscore, matches.matchday

FROM teams AS teamhomescore
INNER JOIN (teams
JOIN matches ON teams.teamid = matches.teamhome) ON teamhomescore.teamid = matches.teamaway
ORDER BY matches.matchdate
```

To get the data in my editform I use next query :

```
SELECT matches.matchid, CONCAT( ELT( DAYOFWEEK( matches.matchdate ) , 'zon', 'maa', 'din', 'woe', 'don', 'vrij', 'zat' ) , ' ', 
DAYOFMONTH( matches.matchdate ) ,
 ' ', 
 ELT( MONTH( matches.matchdate ) , 'jan', 'feb', 'maa', 'apr', 'mei', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec' ) ,' ',
 year( matches.matchdate )) AS datum_NL, 
 TIME_FORMAT( matches.matchtime, '%H:%i' ) AS UUR,
matches.matchtype, matches.division, matches.season, teams.teamname AS thuisploeg, teamhomescore.teamname AS bezoekers, matches.homescore, matches.awayscore, matches.matchday
FROM teams AS teamhomescore
INNER JOIN (
teams
INNER JOIN matches ON teams.teamid = matches.teamhome
) ON teamhomescore.teamid = matches.teamaway
WHERE matchid=$matchid
```

So far so good. 
Now I want to update the data, so there I have a problem. Do I have to reverse the query when I update my record or how I have to do that? 
This is the basic query that I have

```
UPDATE matches SET matchdate='$matchdate', matchtime='$matchtime' , season='$season', division='$division', matchtype='$matchtype' , teamhome='$thuisploeg', teamaway='$teamaway', homescore=IF('$homescore'='',NULL,'$homescore') ,awayscore=IF('$awayscore'='',NULL,'$awayscore'), matchday=$matchday WHERE matchid='$matchid'
```

Comment: Basic query looks ok (besides SQL injection vulberability). What's the problem?

Comment: The first query changed the teamid in a teamname. With the update query I have to change the teamname in an ID and I don't now how I have to start with the update query.